# series of subgroups of the solvable group $Gal(x^6-7) $.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, solvable-groups

I have to solve the following question:

Let $p(x) = x^6-7 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$, then $Gal(p(x)) $ is a solvable group (the splitting field of $p(x)$ is contained in a radical extension).
Give a series of normal subgroups of $Gal(p(x)) $ that satisfy the definition of a solvable group.

Is there a smart way to do this or do I have to calculate the Galois group and then search for correct normal subgroups?

Comment: In characteristic zero when you adjoin an $n$th root of an element to a field containg a primitive $n$th root of unity, you always get a cyclic extension. When you adjoin those roots of unity you get an abelian extension. So starting by adjoining the appropriate roots of unity, and then following any root tower extension will give you this. Do convert the intermediate fields to their corresponding subgroups of the Galois group.

Comment: That's essentially the recipe in proving: Galois group solvable $\Leftrightarrow$ the splitting field is gotten as a root tower extension.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen can you give an explicit series? I'm afraid I don't quite follow.